# How can send file to Firebase using C#

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to send files to Firebase Storage using C#, and I use [this package](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-storage-dotnet) for it.

I wrote the following code to send the file I want to send to Firebase;

```
public static async Task<bool> SendFile(string path, string name)
{
    try
    {
        var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open);

        var task = new FirebaseStorage(Bucket)
            .Child(name)
            .PutAsync(stream);

        var downloadUrl = await task;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The problem is that the code is not working and following line:

```
var downloadUrl = await task;
```

Throws an exception:

> The specified argument was not in the range of valid values. Parameter name: value

But I did not do any user verification. I see this package being used actively, but I have not found any explanatory document.

It also gives the following message in detail as an error message

> Message = "Exception occured while processing the request.\nUrl: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mueasyco-92b3b.appspot.com/o?name=1529582622840.wav\nResponse: N/A"

*EDIT*

I uploaded code;

```
public static async Task SendFile(string path, string name)
        {
            try
            {
                var auth = new FirebaseAuthProvider(new FirebaseConfig(ApiKey));
                var a = await auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password);

                var stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path));

                var task = new FirebaseStorage("mueasyco-92b3b.appspot.com", new FirebaseStorageOptions
                    {
                        AuthTokenAsyncFactory = () => Task.FromResult(a.FirebaseToken),
                        ThrowOnCancel = true
                    })
                    .Child(name)
                    .PutAsync(stream);

                var downloadUrl = await task;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
```

But now I seem to be having problems with asynchronous programming. The code works until the following line;

```
var a = await auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password);
```

However, the rest of the code does not work, I think it is waiting for the process to finish. However, I do not want this method to exit without completing its work.

*EDIT 2*

I invoked the method with `.Wait()`, but the authentication section above does not end.

Comment: maybe the value which you are passing is not the correct

Comment: @D-johnAnshani url checked but I did not find an error, I think the problem is user authentication and I do not know how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: check the flow where you need to upload the file means path and the value first

Comment: @D-johnAnshani Could you tell me more about the check you want me to do please?

Comment: any answer for this issue